# Shoes photography

Tags: lens, product-photography, studio-setup

I am in need for a technical solution for a shooting of shoes. I have this reference:

[image]
[image]

Could someone please advise on the fallowing:

1. Do I need a light box like this one?

[image]

2. What is the correct camera to shoot with (a fullframe maybe?) or will an average DSLR make the job with the correct lens?
3. What is a proper lens to shoot this correctly?
4. What is the kind of light and light setup for this?
5. Is there a particular technique to achieve this (like focus stacking for example)?

The result I want is exactly as in the exmaple I gave. Also if nobody has the time to answer as I imagine is not that simple and this result comes with years of experience, a good tutorial might come handy.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The other question covers tripod + head and background colors.  Doesn't cover lens, body, lighting or focus stacking.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I need that particular kind of shot and not just any kind of average product shot. I guess there is a particular technique for that and / or a combination of lens, camera & light

Comment: Funny that you should bring Alex Koloskov into the question then ask about light boxes. They're almost always the wrong choice, and Alex is one of the most vocal photographic instructors telling people not to use them. By the way, he has [a video on YouTube that's *exactly* on point for your question](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I209ttY180M).

Comment: @mugur that _is_ an average product shot - evenly lit, white background. They've used a slightly reflective surface for the base, but otherwise... average product shot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need full frame.

I would use a medium telephoto lens (80-150mm) to get some distance from the subject.  On a tripod, lens stopped down, you shouldn't need focus stacking

I don't think they've used a light tent.  If you look carefully at the top photo there are two shadows of the heels at 45 degree angles.  So I imagine they've used to large softboxes either side of the camera, and possible an overhead light.  With a light tent, the light is more diffuse and I don't think you'd see as much directional light.  Another possible clue is the highlights in the toes in the bottom photo.  Again I don't think that's shot in a light tent.